# Plot can't be displayed in RMarkdown Presentation

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, rscript, presentation

We've been trying to include a graphic of our plot(s) in the R markdown presentation, but it simply does not work. The code is working and we can see the plot in Rscript and the markdown report, but it doesn't work in the knitted presentation. We used the following code:

##### Boxplot {#plots .flexbox .vcenter}

```
a <- boxplot(student$bmi, col = "lightgreen", 
        main = "BMI allgemein", 
        col.main = "darkgreen", 
        ylab = "BMI (in kg/m^2)",
        ylim = c(0,40))
a
```

as well as a ggplot

##### GGPlot

```
student %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x= Bewegung1, y=bmi, fill= Geschlecht)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ggtitle("Geschlechterspezifische Verteilung des BMI in Abhängigkeit von der Bewegung") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, colour = "darkblue", geom = "point", 
               shape=18, size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,40, by = 5)) +
  labs(x="Selbsteinschätzung der Bewegung in den letzten 7 Tage (60 min/day)", y="BMI")
```

We've tried adding different libraries (like httpuv) as suggested in other forums, but this doesn't work for us. We added the libraries ggplot2, tidyverse, ggtheme, foreign, dplyr and others (not relevant for this code).

We've also tried adding plot() as well as print() after the code and we've also looked at other presentation where it worked, did the exact same thing, but it didn't work for our presentation.
We're completely lost. Please help.

[The output is shown like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Al9ap.png)

Comment: Knitted presentation is .html file? If you are trying to open it in some old version of Internet Explorer, please check with another browser. But it's just a blind shot.

Comment: If you can't get it to work, you could always export the working plot as jpg or png then add that to the rmarkdown file? Just a workaround until you find out what's happening

Comment: The problem could be with the file name. If you have spaces in `.Rpres` file, it might be causing an error. Don't even include numbers or `.html` extension.